# can someone help me fix this batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a notepad program and the creator of the text files doesn't work. can someone help me? I need to add more details before posting, so ignore everything from here except the code.

```
IF [%writeone%]==[] (
    set /p writeone= Name:
    cls
    echo Ok, your file has been created. Have fun!
    pause
    cls
    set /p textone=
    pause
    echo Ok, now your done, you will be redirected to the desktop...
    pause
    goto desktop
) ELSE (
    IF [%writetwo%]==[] (
        set /p writetwo= Name:
        cls
        echo Ok, your file has been created. Have fun!
        pause
        cls
        set /p texttwo=
        pause
        echo Ok, now your done, you will be redirected to the desktop...
        pause
        goto desktop
    )
) ELSE (
    IF [%writethree%]==[] (
        set /p writethree= Name:
        cls
        echo Ok, your file has been created. Have fun!
        pause
        cls
        set /p textthree=
        pause
        echo Ok, now your done, you will be redirected to the desktop...
        pause
        goto desktop
    )
)
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetaur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

Comment: Welocome to SO, @dacadia. You are correct that more information is needed. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on asking questions. Also, what does `goto desktop` mean? There is not `desktop` label in the script.

Comment: I have indented your code both to highlight and supplement the issue I raised in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, strangely enough, we're going to need more info.
As far as I can tell, you're not writing any files.
The easiest way to do this:

```
echo test > filename.extension
```

To create a file named filename.extension containing the word "test".

You can write your variable to your file using `echo %variable% > file`

Without more info I'm afraid it's hard to help.

Comment: No, this writes `test` *followed by a __space__* to the file. Rather write `echo test> "filename.ext"`, or even better, `> "filename.ext" echo test`, to avoid the trailing space...

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be easier to read, and debug, if you were to indent your open blocks. Once done, you should clearly see that you have either an `else` condition without a matching `if` or a misplaced closing parenthesis. Given your code, my experience tells me that it's the latter.

```batch-file
If "%writeone%" == "" (
    Set /P "writeone=Name: "
    ClS
    Echo Ok, your file has been created. Have fun!
    Pause
    ClS
    Set /P "textone="
    Pause
    Echo Ok, now your done, you will be redirected to the desktop...
    Pause
    GoTo desktop
) Else (
    If "%writetwo%" == "" (
        Set /P "writetwo=Name: "
        ClS
        Echo Ok, your file has been created. Have fun!
        Pause
        ClS
        Set /P "texttwo="
        Pause
        Echo Ok, now your done, you will be redirected to the desktop...
        Pause
        GoTo desktop
    ) Else (
        If "%writethree%" == "" (
            Set /P "writethree=Name: "
            ClS
            Echo Ok, your file has been created. Have fun!
            Pause
            ClS
            Set /P "textthree="
            Pause
            Echo Ok, now your done, you will be redirected to the desktop...
            Pause
            GoTo desktop
        )
    )
)
```

Please also note that I've replaced your poor implementation `IF [%variable%]==[]`, with `If "%variable%" == ""` and include protective doublequotes around your `set /p` commands. In addition it should be worth mentioning, that you appear to be requesting input, without prompting the end user with what you want them to insert, for defining the variables named `textone`, `texttwo` and `textthree`, I would suggest that you modify it similar to your `writeone`, `writetwo` and `writethree` examples.

---

However, I'm not sure you actually needed the `else` conditions at all. The following is probably all you needed:

```batch-file
If "%writeone%" == "" (
    Set /P "writeone=Name: "
    ClS
    Echo Ok, your file has been created. Have fun!
    Pause
    ClS
    Set /P "textone="
    Pause
    Echo Ok, now your done, you will be redirected to the desktop...
    Pause
    GoTo desktop
If "%writetwo%" == "" (
    Set /P "writetwo=Name: "
    ClS
    Echo Ok, your file has been created. Have fun!
    Pause
    ClS
    Set /P "texttwo="
    Pause
    Echo Ok, now your done, you will be redirected to the desktop...
    Pause
    GoTo desktop
If "%writethree%" == "" (
    Set /P "writethree=Name: "
    ClS
    Echo Ok, your file has been created. Have fun!
    Pause
    ClS
    Set /P "textthree="
    Pause
    Echo Ok, now your done, you will be redirected to the desktop...
    Pause
    GoTo desktop
)
```